# AWS Lightsail Wordpress Managed MySQL Database mysqldump command not found

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I am following the guide here: https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-connect-wordpress-to-mysql-managed-database

On step 2.3 it asks me to type in the command:

`mysqldump -u root --databases bitnami_wordpress --single-transaction --compress --order-by-primary -p$(cat /home/bitnami/bitnami_application_password) | mysql -u DbUserName --host DbEndpoint --password`

(after swapping out the username and endpoint).

When I do this I get the response:

```
-bash: mysql: command not found
-bash: mysqldump: command not found
```

I found that the mysql and mysqldump commands are not on the path so I looked around and found them in `/opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/`

When I try to run them from there (or cd into that directory) I get:

```
-bash: /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysql: Permission denied
-bash: /opt/bitnami/mysql/bin/mysqldump: Permission denied
```

I also tried assuming the role of root `su root` using the password in `/home/bitnami/bitnami_application_password` but that results in:

```
su: Authentication failure
```

Answer (score 0):

This took me a while to figure out but I found the answer here: https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/how-to/troubleshoot-permission-issues/ at the bottom of the page.  After I ran:

```
 sudo /opt/bitnami/use_wordpress
```

my bash environment was updated and I was able to run the original commands.